# Is programming the same with Phonegap Cordova and Phonegap Desktop

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-desktop-app

I recently downloaded Phonegap Desktop and the docs are very poor and have no info on how to actually build an app. Is it similar to the old version(Cordova)? Can I use the old docs for help on making an app with Phonegap Desktop?

Comment: PhoneGap desktop is just an alternative to the phonegap/Cordova CLI, it does almost everything that the CLI can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the PhoneGap Desktop App is designed to introduce developers to PhoneGap development, provide a quick start and allow them to immediately preview their projects on a mobile device without using the CLI.

The PhoneGap Desktop currently does not support building / compiling your project for distribution.

Template support, building/compiling projects are all features that will be added to the PhoneGap Desktop throughout the rest of the year.